# how to store 2 variable value in db withh <br> in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to store 2 variable value into a single variable in laravel but fail eg

```
$var = 123;
 $var1 = 345;
 $customer->ot_location = $var.<br>/$var1;
 $customer->save();

result should be 123
                 /345
```

Comment: Keep in mind that data is escaped when you print it with `{{ $customer->ot_location }}`. That includes HTML.

Comment: you mean <br> only?

Comment: `<br />` is HTML, and will be escaped when you print it with `{{ .. }}`.

Comment: yes i understand and i also wantd it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$customer->ot_location = $var.'<br>/'.$var1;
$customer->save();
```